# Clojure Function Error "Key must be integer"

Tags: clojure

I have a problem in this function although it compiles without errors!

The function gets two vectors with the same length `n`, another vector with length `2^n`, and an index. The function does a simple calculation and then returns a vector.

The problem appears when trying to call the function. For example:

```
(check [1 2 3] [1 2 3] [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8] 1)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key must be integer (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
```

Function definition:

```
(defn check [row1 row2 arr j]
  (
   (def x1 (nth arr (nth row1 j)))
   (def x2 (nth arr (nth row2 (- j 1))))
   (def x3 (nth arr (nth row1 (- j 1))))
   (if (<= x1 x2)
     (
      (def row1 (assoc row1 j x3))
      row1
      )
     ((def row1 (assoc row1 (- j 1) x2))
      row1)
     )
   )
  )
```

Comment: perhaps you could say what the problem is, and what the function is supposed to do?

Comment: 1. you can't have `def` forms inside a `defn` form in Clojure. 2. your `let` forms are not syntactically correct Clojure code. Surely that code snippet doesn't compile...

Comment: I have changed let and used def ! It compile but still fail in running mode !

Comment: What's the error message that you get? And what would you expect the output of `(check [1 2 3] [1 2 3] [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8] 1)` to be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I cleaned up your code to this:

```
(defn check [row1 row2 arr j]
  (let [x1 (nth arr (nth row1 j))
        x2 (nth arr (nth row2 (- j 1)))
        x3 (nth arr (nth row1 (- j 1)))]
    (if (<= x1 x2)
        (assoc row1 j x3)
        (assoc row1 (- j 1) x2))))
```

I have no idea if that does what you want it to do, but the function evaluates, and returns sensible values, e.g.

```
user=> (check [1 2 3] [1 2 3] [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8] 1)
[2 2 3]
```

Comment: @FayezAbdlrazaqDeab great! Please read through mikera's answer and compare my code to yours to understand what was wrong with your original code.

Answer (score 5):

You should probably try to fix the following problems before anything else:

- Don't use [def](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/def) inside a function, you should use `(let [name1 value1 name2 value2] ...)` instead. def is really for defining something in a namespace, not for local values.
- Your lets have a syntax problem, it should be `(let [row1 (assoc row1 j x3)] ...)` for example
- The parenthesis on line 2 mean that you are calling the result of `(def x1 (nth arr (nth row1 j)))` as a function. This almost certainly isn't what you want. Turning the defs into a let should help solve this.

Comment: thank you mikera but after the change that I did it still deosnt work